# ggplot facets of plots of sum of data, rather than data itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum, facet

I'm trying to produce a plot of sums of a particular variable over time by facet in ggplot.  I'm working on a school assignment, so I will use the built-in mpg data set for this question rather than the actual data.

One task is to plot the displacement by year for each class in mpg. The code

```
qplot(data = mpg, year, displ, facets = . ~ class)
```

produces the desired result.  But for the next question, I have to produce nearly the same plot but plot the *sum* of the displacements by year for each class, and I can't seem to do it.  I've tried variations of `tapply` to no avail.  I had hoped that

```
qplot(data = mpg, year, sum(displ), facets = . ~ class)
```

would do it but it did not.

Comment: you need to change the data fed to qplot with tapply or with group_by from dplyr for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `stat_summary` and skipping qplot:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y = displ)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="sum", geom="point") + facet_grid(.~class)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could try this with `dplyr` too:

```
library(dplyr)
mpg %>% group_by(year, class) %>% summarise(displ=sum(displ)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, displ)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~class)
```

[image]